# Regular expression to check formula

Tags: javascript, regex

Been trying now for a bit but can't figure this one out, I need a regular expression in Javascript that will match any term that only contains any of the following characters:

The digits 0-9, the minus sign (-), divide (/), multiply (*), plus (+), space ( ), left and right brackets ( ( and ) ), dot (.) and then lastly a comma (,).

If it contains anything else I want it to return false. It can contain multiples of each or only some of the characters in this set. What I have so far:

```
var regExResult = someString.test(/([^A-Z][^a-z][0-9]|[-]|[\+]|[*]|[,]|[.]|[)]|[(]|[\/]|[ ])+/g);
```

But for some reason it returns true even if the string contains only one character of these mentioned?

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks

Comment: You can wrap all chars in the same [ ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that check as:

`^[0-9*+ ().,-]+$`

Demo: http://regex101.com/r/yK2cG5

Comment: No need to escape all these chars: `[0-9*+ ().,-]`

Comment: What if user inputs double plus sign in between digits?

Comment: This regex considers `1-+*2` as correct.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example code

```
var str = '1234-/*()., '; // results in 'good' alert
var str = '12a34-/*()., '; // results in 'bad' alert

if (/[^0-9-/*()., ]/.test(str)) { // true if it finds anything that is not allowed
  alert('bad');
}
else { // if it didn't finds anything that is not allowed 
  alert('good');
}
```

Good luck
:)